# How do stream a file from WCF that didn't originate from a filesystem. (sharepoint content database)

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, filestream, memorystream

I'm trying to return a stream in WCF 3.5 using a REST-Style URL instead of SOAP.  The idea is to read a file from SharePoint 2010, then pass it back to the client.  (We have reasons for doing it this way instead of using SharePoint services, but I digress.)  It appears as though the only way to send the file is by writing it to the filesystem using one `FileStream`, then using `File.OpenRead` to return the stream back to the client.  Using a `MemoryStream` doesn't seem to work.  IE prompts for the file save, but the file comes down as like 2KB and then can't be read of course because it's not all there.  Any ideas?

```
SPListItemCollection lookupFld2 = docLibrary.GetItems(spQuery2);  

if (lookupFld2.Count > 0)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = 
      "application/octet-stream";

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(
      "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + lookupFld2[0].File.Name);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = 
      (MemoryStream)lookupFld2[0].File.OpenBinaryStream();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, OpenBinaryStream only returns a general Stream instance NOT a MemoryStream (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470901.aspx). If you want a MemoryStream you need to create a new one and copy the contents from the BinaryStream into the MemoryStream then reset the position and return it.